# SIGINT callback prints twice

Tags: c, ipc, sigint

i'm trying to start a IPC's related project and under my point of view I have to start handling signals. When it's time to press `Ctrl`+`C` the handler function starts correctly but in console it appears printed twice.

Another curious situation is that if I change the character to an empty string, the parent process sleeps 10 secs properly and then receives the `SIGINT`.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
void handler(int);
/*typedef struct {
int semaforo;
//iremos añadiendo mas a medida que necesitemos, pero para pasar todos como un
solo argumento a la función manejadora es más comodo. }ipces;*/
int semaforo;
int main() {
    // ipces ipces;
    semaforo = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0600);

    semctl(semaforo, 0, SETVAL, 1);

    struct sigaction newact, oldact;
    struct sembuf semoper, semoper1;
    sigset_t mask;

    newact.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    // nueva.sa_mask=mask;
    // newact.sa_flags=SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &newact, &oldact);

    int pid = fork();

    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            perror("Error en el forking");
            kill(getpid(), SIGINT);  // envía sigint a el mismo proceso que lo
                                     // invoca, e inicia la manejadora
            break;

        case 0:  // hijo
            while (1) {
                printf("*");
            }

            break;

        default:

            semoper.sem_op = -1;
            semoper.sem_num = 0;
            semop(semaforo, &semoper, 0);
            sleep(10);
            // hacemos que haga cosas y si todo ha ido bien lanzamos SIGINT ->
            // LANZARÁ LA MANEJADORA
            kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
            break;
    }
}
void handler(int sig) {
    printf("SIGINT");

    if (semctl(semaforo, 0, IPC_RMID) == 1) {
        printf("Error borrando semaforo;");
    }
    // system("clear");
    exit(3);
}
```

Comment: just added `<unistd.h>` but the parent process only gets SIGINT after sleeping 10 secs when child process prints an empty string.

Comment: None of the functions you use in the signal handler are safe to use when the signal is generated asynchronously (such as by a user hitting ctrl-c). List of okay ones: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: Thanks i think thats what i'm looking for